# why return 401 when invoke apple rest api to get subscribe status

Tags: java

I want to invoke apple get subscribe status [api](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/get_all_subscription_statuses), read the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreserverapi/generating_tokens_for_api_requests) to generate auth token. This is my java code:

```
public static void getSubscribeStatus(String originalTransactionId) {
        AppleJwtHeader appleJwtHeader = new AppleJwtHeader();
        appleJwtHeader.setAlg("ES256");
        appleJwtHeader.setKid("UYTRH4AF9");
        appleJwtHeader.setTyp("JWT");
        AppleJwtPayload appleJwtPayload = new AppleJwtPayload();
        appleJwtPayload.setIss("5fbe8236-27d7-4390-8f40-008acd64a29d");
        appleJwtPayload.setIat(System.currentTimeMillis());
        appleJwtPayload.setExp(System.currentTimeMillis() + 1000 * 60 * 15);
        appleJwtPayload.setAud("appstoreconnect-v1");
        appleJwtPayload.setNonce(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
        appleJwtPayload.setBid("com.moon.dol");
        String jwtAuthToken = AuthUtil.generateToken(appleJwtHeader,appleJwtPayload);
        AppleRestClient client = RetrofitUtil.retrofit.create(AppleRestClient.class);
        Call<SubscribeStatusResponse> call = client.getSubscribeStatus("Bearer " + jwtAuthToken,originalTransactionId);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<SubscribeStatusResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<SubscribeStatusResponse> call, Response<SubscribeStatusResponse> response) {
                log.info("success:" + JSON.toJSONString(response));
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<SubscribeStatusResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                log.error("failed，originalTransctionId：" + originalTransactionId, t);
            }
        });

    }
```

and this is the interface define:

```
public interface AppleRestClient {

    /**
     * @param originalTransactionId
     * @return
     */
    @GET("/inApps/v1/subscriptions/{originalTransactionId}")
    Call<SubscribeStatusResponse> getSubscribeStatus(@Header("Authorization") String token,
            @Path("originalTransactionId") String originalTransactionId
    );

}
```

but when I invoke the function to get subscribe status, the response still return 401 code:

```
Response{protocol=h2, code=401, message=, url=https://api.storekit-sandbox.itunes.apple.com/inApps/v1/subscriptions/1000000835857631}
```

why still return 401 after pass auth token in header of http request? where am I doing wrong? I also tried using curl command:

```
curl -v -H 'Authorization: Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzUiOiJKVMiOiI1ZmI4ZTgzNi0E2MjYyMzczNjAwNzIsImV4cCI6MTYiwiYXVkIjoiYXBwc3' "https://api.storekit-sandbox.itunes.apple.com/inApps/v1/subscriptions/1000000835857631"
```

still did not work.

```
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Server: daiquiri/3.0.0
< Date: Wed, 14 Jul 2021 04:49:21 GMT
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
< X-Apple-Jingle-Correlation-Key: PGJM5VZU2UXJTK33BQK7H23JO4
< x-daiquiri-instance: daiquiri:17578001:mr85p00it-hyhk04164801:7987:21HOTFIX14
<
Unauthenticated

Request ID: PGJM5VZU2UXJTK33BQK7H23JO4.0.0
* Connection #0 to host api.storekit-sandbox.itunes.apple.com left intact
```

I also tried to tweak the time from miniseconds to second like this:

```
appleJwtPayload.setIat(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000L);
appleJwtPayload.setExp(System.currentTimeMillis()/1000L +   60 * 15);
```

still not work.

Answer (score 0):

Apple return 401 tells the client generate token have some problem. So you should make sure using the right way to generate token. In my case, one mistake is that I did not get the right way to get private key from apple p8 file. the other mistake is that I use the minisecond of the unix timestamp, change it to second. The way to get private key like this:

```
public static PrivateKey getPrivateKey(String filename, String algorithm) throws IOException {
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(filename)), "utf-8");
        try {
            String privateKey = content.replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
                    .replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "")
                    .replaceAll("\\s+", "");

            KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm);
            return kf.generatePrivate(
                    new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKey)));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("java did not support" + algorithm, e);
        } catch (InvalidKeySpecException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("invalid format");
        }
    }
```

and invoke it like this:

```
    PrivateKey appleKey = SecurityUtil.getPrivateKey("/opt/apps/dolphin-post/AuthKey_YDKL424AF9.p8","EC");
```

hope this help for you.